# jQuery - Toggle play/pause button (Multiple audios)

Tags: jquery, html, audio, toggle

I want to show different titles and each of them have to play their own sound (with a play/pause toggle).

Each of these buttons has to get its own unique sound by using the `<audio></audio>` tag.

I'm not a hero in jQuery (yet), but I've made a start. But from now, I don't no what to do.

Can somebody please help me with this?

I've made an jsfiddle to show you what I already got.

http://jsfiddle.net/carloc/7341jxv6/

Thank you very much!

Comment: it would be good if you include that fiddle code here too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just changing the class, you actually need to call play and pause for the element. refer **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7341jxv6/2/)**

HTML

```
<h2>Sound 1</h2>
<div class="play" id="btn1">play</div>

<h2>Sound 2</h2>
<div class="play" id="btn2">play</div>

<h2>Sound 3</h2>
<div class="play" id="btn3">play</div>


<!-- SOUNDS -->
<audio id="sound1">
    <source src="http://www.bigsoundbank.com/sounds/ogg/0595.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>

<audio id="sound2">
    <source src="http://www.bigsoundbank.com/sounds/ogg/0580.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>

<audio id="sound3">
    <source src="http://www.bigsoundbank.com/sounds/ogg/0003.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

Script -

```
$('.play').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('id').replace(/btn/, '');
    $this.toggleClass('active');
    if($this.hasClass('active')){
        $this.text('pause'); 
        $('audio[id^="sound"]')[id-1].play();        
    } else {
        $this.text('play');
        $('audio[id^="sound"]')[id-1].pause();
    }
});
```

Here ^= is the starts with selector, which selects all audios and using id of the button, we actually play or pause the exact clicked audio.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're asking for.

You can use JQuery for starting and pausing like this:

```
$('#sound1').trigger('play');
```

and

```
$('#sound1').trigger('pause');
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be the function u expected :)

using `.trigger('play') and .trigger('pause')`

**[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/34a0vfL5/)**